# How do I add file paths as nodes to a tree or stack in C++

Tags: c++, tree, stack, filesystems, queue

I have a project to search, rename or delete files and folders on a selected drive on the computer using a data structure(A tree, a stack, or a queue).  My question is, how do I add file paths and directories as nodes in C++?

Comment: Check [`boost::filesystem`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm). Standard c++ doesn't have any notion about filesystems (yet).

Comment: files and folders are strings.  perhaps your 'nodes' might contain a string?

Comment: Oh.  Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN
It does contain a string for the data portion, but what I need to know is how to assign all the files and folders to it.  If it's possible

Comment: File systems are host dependent ... are you on Window, Linux, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment in other answer suggests using one of the exec() functions.  Then parsing and studying the output.

I approve of that idea, but I find it easier to use popen().  Each of the following examples are part of the Linux API, so the calls are c compatible and can be used directly by C++.  I expect popen() will be available on other OS's.

To clarify,

1) popen() is a function call for your C++ code to invoke.

2) You will also need to create strings for your OS to generate the lists you want, and submit them to your invocation of popen().  The 1st parameter is the command string

3) in read mode, the output of your "ls -lsa " or "dir" command will be written into the output pipe of the spawned process, and your code will need to 'suck it in', I recommend capturing it to a std::stringstream.

4) after capture of the "dir -r" output, then parse and extract dir's and file names from the stringstream.

---

Examples of C++ access to popen:

```
FILE* m_pipe = nullptr; // popen return a FILE*


// use m_pipe to read from sub-process std::out
m_pipe = ::popen (m_cmd.c_str(), "r");  // read mode
//       ^^ because popen is not in a namespace


m_pipe = ::popen(m_cmd.c_str(), "w"); // write to sub-process std::in

int32_t pcloseStat = ::pclose(m_pipe);



{
   (void)memset(buff, 0, BUFF_SIZE);

   // Reads characters from stream and stores them as a C string
   // into buff until
   //    a) (BUFF_SIZE-1) characters have been read or
   //    b) a newline or
   //    c) the end-of-file is reached,
   // whichever happens first.
   char* stat = fgets (buff, BUFF_SIZE, m_pipe); // returns buff or null
   int myErrno = errno;               //^^^^^^ -- created by popen
}
```

---

Example of building a linux command for popen 1st parameter ...

```
  std::string md5sumCmd ("head --bytes=1M " + mPFN +" | md5sum");
```

This command grabs the 1st 1Megabyte of file name in mPFN (a std::string), and pipes that output into md5sum ... essentially generating an md5sum of the 1s Meg of the file.  The md5sum output is what will be received by the calling process.

---

You will need to create appropriate commands (to pass to popen) to show dir's and folder's and file names, etc.

What ever works from the command line should be fine, but some options might make parsing the output easier.

Comment: The last time I dealt with the Window NT file system, there were 'short cuts' which are difficult to handle.  Probably still exist.

Comment: Remember about file access privileges.  In Linux, you should not try to start from root.  And there seems to be plenty of dir paths in any file system you should avoid.  I recommend start your effort by working with one of your personal directories.  i.e. the ::popen ("ls -lsar  /home/name/temp", "r")

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to popen.  I use windows so it takes the form _popen.  I did [This Code](http://pastebin.com/CXE36uca) to test it out, but it prints only the folder that the project is in.  Is that how it's intended to work?

Comment: @DaneJackson    No.  Not how it should work.  Your code looks ok to me.  I copy / paste'd your code into a Linux work directory, changed underscore prefix to '::' prefix, added some line feeds, and your code worked as I expected, multiple lines.  Sorry, I don't have a C++ compiler on my Windows laptop.  To me it appears you are on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

For your node based structures, add a string property that would serve as your file path. You might need to replace "\" with "/" in it however as the forward slash is often an escape character in most languages. For example in a queue:

```
class Node {
Node next;
char[50] path;
}
```

And you can create accessors and mutators the same way you would anything else in a class. This will allow you to assign it values and to read the values. 
Folders could be used as a parent and the files are children. A tree structure would likely be the easiest way to do this.

Comment: @ CS2016  
Adding "C:/" as a string will only display C:/ when the program runs.  Currently I have the tree class:

[My Tree Class](http://pastebin.com/AmER0Pm8)  ( I don't know how to paste my code here )

But when I call the InOrder function after passing "C:/" to my node.  what is printed aren't the directories, just what was past to it.

Comment: Are you looking for the program to list all of the files in the directory?

Comment: Yes, that's what is puzzling me.  I'm still a novice programmer, so I don't know of a built in library to accomplish this, I've been seeing people using an external boost library, but my professor says there are ways to get it done in C++ without boost.   The project is to be able to list the files and folders in a directory, search for instances of files or folders and provide the option to delete or rename them.

Comment: I actually had a project similar to this in C, I'll include the code.

Comment: If you can, that would be great!  Thank you.

Comment: You can use system calls to do anything you can do in command prompt, such as "ls" to print the contents of the current directory if you're using a unix machine or "dir" to do the exact same in Windows.  This is how you'd accomplish this in C and the C++ implementation is similar using cout statements. 

`printf("\n", system("ls"));`

This calls the system and requests the "ls" command since I'm using a unix system. You can change this to 

`printf("\n", system("dir"));`

for windows. If you need help with the other commands look up the system commands for your system.

Comment: To change the name of a file, try something like this 

`system("mv old-file-name new-file-name")`  that's the pseudo code to rename a file, try looking up "Unix system commands" for other commands. They have to be in quotes when you pass them to the system call because you're passing it the raw text.

Comment: Thank you for that information! [I tried this short code to test it](http://pastebin.com/6QC4tnP1), but it also prints only the directory that the project is found in.  I appreciate the help thus far.

Comment: @DaneJackson  Well, I don't know much about Windows code.  But maybe the exec family does not redirect the process output to C++ stream (as easily as on popen).  Maybe try again, but as:     "cout <<  "\n";  system("dir");"